# Calling server function using jquery and returning with result

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, treeview

I have created a treeview which has function to move the nodes up / down. The function to move up / down is called in jquery. The jQuery code is

```
 $("#move_up").live("click", function(e) {
            var rqdInstnId = GetRequiredId();
            $.post("/Instruction/MoveInstruction", { docId: DocId, instnId: rqdInstnId, action: "MoveUp" });
        });
```

I need to reflect the changes in the treeview after the function is performed. Now the treeview is loaded to a div. Can this be attained by using iframe? Please clarify me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
$(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
```

http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/